# Connect MySQL through JDBC in filebeats in Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

I am not able to connect MySQL in filebeats in Elastic Cloud.
No error I am getting.

Can anyone guide me how to do it ?

This configuration I'm using

```
 input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://connectionstring"
            jdbc_user => "username"
            jdbc_password => "password"
            schedule => "* * * * *"
            statement => "SELECT * from tablename"
        }
    }
    
    output {
        stdout { codec => json_lines }
        elasticsearch {
            "hosts" => "hostId"
            "index" => "index"
            "document_type" => "data"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your Filebeat configuration (without the hostname, user, and password of Elastic Cloud) and the logs of Filebeat?

Comment: @xeraa Updated the configuration. please check

Comment: Ok, so this is Logstash (and no Filebeat needed in this scenario). Can you show the log of Logstash — especially the connection to MySQL and Elasticsearch?